# Access/VBA and SQL WHERE clause format issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, where-clause, ms-access-2003

I have read a huge pile of problems and solutions, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
BounceDate = DateValue(txtBounceDate.Value)
bncSql = "DELETE _BounceMaster.* FROM _BounceMaster" & _
    " WHERE _BounceMaster.DateCheck >= #" & BounceDate & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSQL bncSql
```

_BounceMaster.DateCheck is in Date/Time format, which I think may be the issue, but I can't figure out what different format it should be in, or how to get there. As best as I can tell, BounceDate is correct - even using CDate didn't make a idfference. I have gotten both data mismatch errors, and currently, with code as above, I am getting syntax errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Watch out for locale problems with dates. It is nearly always best to format dates to year, month, day to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
DELETE FROM _BounceMaster
```

not

```
DELETE _BounceMaster.* FROM _BounceMaster
```

You should be using parameterized queries, as your code is subject to SQL injection attack.

Comment: According to my references, either way is perfectly valid - the table.* is optional before FROM. As to parameterized queries - I'm new enough at this that I don't know what that means.

Comment: Hard code a date to make sure your syntax is correct first, then proceed from there. [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: D'oh! I hadn't thought about hard coding a date. It's not working still, but maybe I'll figure out how to fix it from there. I'm not worried about SQL injection as this database is internal only, and will be protected in other ways.

Comment: Even with a hardcoded date, and the table.* deleted, I still get syntax errors.

Comment: It was the _ before the table name that was causing the syntax error.

Comment: The BounceDate variable was set in the wrong place. I moved it to the procedure, instead of the module, and it worked fine. I don't know why that made a difference, but it worked, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem comes from date formatting. The `BounceDate` variable is DateTime type, so when you concatenate with string type variable, VBA automatically casts DateTime variable into String type using date format from your regional settings.

As I correctly remember, SQL interpreter from MS Access feels comfortable only with mm/dd/yyyy date format, so please try this:

```
BounceDate = DateValue(txtBounceDate.Value)
bncSql = "DELETE _BounceMaster.* FROM _BounceMaster" & _
    " WHERE _BounceMaster.DateCheck >= #" & Format(BounceDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSQL bncSql
```